# Set variable not working inside message handler

Tags: events, mit-scratch

I think I am missing something here. I have super simple case where I want to use flag as a semaphore. If I press [green flag] setting value back to 0 works just fine. If I press [space], flag is not set after sound is played. Am I missing something here? What happens inside message handler? Is it overtaken by next call to message handler?

https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/82146090/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how the message is being called.

I did this test of your code.

[image: Event loop in scratch]

When the loop fires the message, a counter increments, showing you how many times the firing occurs.

The first bar-press I did, 'test' was incremented to over 4000. In other words, the message was fired over 4000 times! I'm a slow typist but the events are fast.

Now it appears that in Scratch, each message broadcast interrupts the previous one. As 'play sound' is long to execute, message1 never gets to the end without interruption, the final instructions are never executed and flag2 is not set to 0.

There are several workarounds:

[image: move 'set' outside the if]

Place the flag-setting outside the scope of if. As the second message interrupts the first and runs, it zeroes the flag.

[image: use 'and wait']

Make sure the current message is not interrupted by a new one by using 'and wait'. Thus no interruption, the message executes in full.

[image]

Avoid messages. Use scratch's own event loop. Do you really need the loop to fire over 4,000 messages for 1 key press? Let Scratch handle events its way.